# What are the implications of migrating from createWebHashHistory() to createWebHistory()?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an application that I released that uses `createWebHashHistory()` to manage URLs. For example, a user visits the following URL to visit something called the earthquakes channel:

```
https://app.radar.chat/#/channel/earthquakes
```

I would like to switch over to using `createWebHistory()` to manage URLs instead (SEO, social media previews, iOS universal links configuration, etc). With that in mind, I would like it if my new URL structure looks like this:

```
https://app.radar.chat/channel/earthquakes
```

I know that to support this change I need to make a server change. The easiest way is to have the server redirect incoming requests to an index.html file (this is [documented extensively on the Vue website](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)).

However, there are URLs in the wild that link to these old pages, URLs that have been printed and that can never be updated.

Is there a convenient mechanism to continue to support the old hash-based URLs while having the non-hashed URLs be the new default?

Comment: Actually, in my testing, by using the `createWebHistory()` history mode Vue will automatically redirect _most_ URLs that match the pattern. However, I am seeing that more complex routes that contain regular expressions aren't redirecting as expected.

Comment: Hmm. I cannot reproduce the automatic redirect you're seeing. An explicit config is needed in my tests. What are examples of the complex routes you're referring to?

Comment: @tony19, turns out the automatic redirect only happens when I run a local Vue dev server. In production the redirect doesn't happen at all. For the local Vue dev server, if I open `/#/foo`, it'll redirect to `/foo`. it seems to work with basic routes and those with simple `:foo_id` patterns, but not with full regex paths.

Comment: Interesting. That doesn't occur with the default setup of Vite. Perhaps you're using Vue CLI's Webpack dev server.

Comment: @tony19 that I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your router config, you could add a [global `beforeEach` hook](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) on the index path that resolves to the hash path in the URL if it exists:

```js
// router.js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [⋯]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.path === '/' && to.hash.startsWith('#/')) {
    next(to.hash.substr(1))
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-router-hash-to-web-history?file=src%2Frouter.js)

Comment: That appears to have done the trick! I was about to write similar code checking the `location` object before the Vue app runs but this is much cleaner.